# AJAX to load XML with images

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I'm new to the world of AJAX, so please forgive my n00bishness. I have an XML document which looks like this:

```
<juices>
<smoothie id="SY4301">
    <name>Strawberry Yumghurt</name>
    <price currency="GBP">
        <perunit type="wholesale">1.23</perunit>
        <perunit type="RRP">1.89</perunit>
        <percrate>28.50</percrate>
    </price>
    <description>Velvety yoghurt smoothie made with fresh strawberry and rasperries.</description>
    <ingredients>
        <ingredient image="/images/strawberry.jpg" quantity="9">Strawberries</ingredient>
        <ingredient image="/images/Raspberry.jpg" quantity="4">Raspberries</ingredient>
        <ingredient image="/images/yoghurt.jpg"quantity="200ml">Greek Yoghurt</ingredient>
        <ingredient image="/images/honey.jpg" quantity="30ml">Runny Honey</ingredient>
        <ingredient image="/images/milk.jpg"quantity="40ml">Semi-skimmed Milk</ingredient>
    </ingredients>
    <nutrition per="100ml">
        <kcal unit="cal">140</kcal>
        <kjoules unit="KJ">442</kjoules>
        <carbohydrate unit="g">27.9</carbohydrate>
        <protein unit="g">1.4</protein>
        <fat unit="g">8.4</fat>
        <fibre unit="g">2.8</fibre>
    </nutrition>
    <imageloc>http://www5.bbk.ac.uk/~akaufm01/jvfma/Images/Products/morning_kick.jpg</imageloc>
</smoothie>
</juices>
```

I have an XSL document that is loading everything but the ingredients on page load, but what I want to achieve is that on clicking (link or button, I don't mind which), replace the contents of one of the divs (#description) with a list of the ingredients accompanied by its image, the location of which is stored in the image attribute.

I have looked at some tutorials which suggest using jQuery to achieve this but I haven't had much luck in getting this to work. I know I could also use the XMLHttpRequest function in JS but not sure which method is better.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

well first you need to understand what are you doing with the ajax because there different ways to make an ajax called with jquery, let's use the basic attributes

```
//Handle the ajax in the event click of your button with ID MyButton
$('#MyButton').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
       type: "Type of your http Request could be GEt or Post",
       url: " the url where you obtain that xml",
       data: "ïf you need to pass some data to the url"
       dataType: "in your case should be XML which is the data type that you're going to handle in the success function",
       success: function(data){ 
            //parse your xml which it contains in the var data
            //You could set the data parse in your div with a append or html method
       }'define a function or put a function already defined',
       error: 'define a function in case of error'
    });
});
```

[Here's the doc about an ajax in jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

[Here's you can find the documentation of the method about](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

[And here how you can parse an xml using jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

Comment: `$('#MyButton').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                   type: "GET",
                   url: "smoothies.xml",
                   dataType: "XML",
                   success: function(data){ 
                       
                        $(xml).find('node').each(function(){ 
                var title = $(this).find('ingredient').text();  
                $('#Description').append($(this).find('name').text());
                   }'define a function or put a function already defined',
                   error: alert('Error');
                });
            });`

Comment: I've added this jQuery but it's not doing anything. Any ideas?

Comment: i'm my code i have only a stub you cannot copy and paste and it's going to work. Remove the çomments after the success method